# Why genes are assumed to follow multivariate normal?

Tags: bioinformatics

I wonder why gene expression data are very frequently modeled by multivariate normal distributions. What is the reason for those strong assumptions that the genes follow multivariate gaussian? Are there any reasons specific for genetics other than the reasons for general gaussian assumptions (mathematical convenience, etc.)?

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of what you are referring to? Context would help a great deal in answering this question, as the model of gene expression is greatly dependent on the scientific questions one is asking. If you are interested in modeling the temporal aspects of gene expression, this article is really good: [**LINK**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwDLtETWZT5IaEgwaFZsMHU4N0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It depends on how the data is collected - I'm guessing you're talking about something like a microarray experiment?  Note that the expression levels themselves aren't assumed to be normally distributed.  First there is A LOT of cleanup and normalization and then after a log transformation we make the assumption of normality.

Comment: I am talking about microarray experiments, and not about temporal aspects. So, I think not for every type of dataset we can make a gaussian assumption even after the cleanup, normalization and log transformation processes. I mean, what makes the gaussian assumption eventually possible for microarray data?

Answer (score 2):

The multivariate normal is used because of the Central Limit Theorem - which essentially states that as your sample size increases it converges to the normal distribution.

When you're doing microarray experiments, you are doing pairwise comparisons of two samples (the treated sample and the untreated sample). For inference to be meaningful, obviously you can't just grown one sample and have one untreated sample. You need to repeat the experiment numerous times.

To get meaningful results (even by non-parametric considerations) you need a sample of 30 (so 30 treated samples and 30 untreated samples). Even if you're going the non-parametric route, by Chebyshev's Rule a sample of 30 is enough to get you meaningful results.

If your sample is smaller than 30, the Binomial distribution is appropriate. But again, as your sample size increases you are converging on the normal distribution.

Comment: can you point to a reference for your first sentence (then interpretation of the CLT is one that is unknown to me)?

Comment: Here is a free version http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralLimitTheorem.html

The links to the textbooks in the article are also very good at further explaining it. 

The Normal distribution is present just about everywhere, not just in biostatistics.

Comment: To clarify, the CLT states that the sampling distribution of the sample mean converges to a normal distribution, even if the underlying population distribution is non-normal. So if all your interested in is average gene expression, then the CLT explains why to use a normal distribution. [(video link)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNm3M9cqWyc) [(examples)](http://www.statisticalengineering.com/central_limit_theorem.html)